# Mix Portrait and Landscape in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, landscape, portrait

I am preparing a report and currently I have a portrait and landscape subreports, I want to mix them in one report.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to combine landscape and portrait subreports, you need a new section for ever subreport.

Right click on one of the section and select "Section expert", from here you can add new sections by clicking on an existing section (header, details, footer) and the Add button on the "Paging" tab on the right you can decide the orientation of you section (Default (portrait), landscape and portrait).

Now create your subreport and put it in the new section.

For a portrait subreport just follow the default creation procedure.

For a landscape subreport create a landscape oriented section and in the subreport set landscape orientation in each section of the subreport.

Page Header and Page Footer won't allow you to change the orientation, so in your landscape subreport suppress those section without drill down (right click on the section to find this option) or Crystal Report will act weird and create a new page for every section with different orientation and suppressing them will prevent this situation.

At the end you will have a situation like this
[image: landscape and portrait sections]

Answer (score 0):

If a main report is set to portrait orientation and the subreport is set to landscape, the subreport will print landscape, on a portrait oriented page, thus resulting in data being cut off. In the reverse scenario, main report is landscape, subreport portrait, the subreport will print portrait on a landscape oriented paper and as above, data will be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Crystal Reports 10. It doesn't has "Paging" tab in Section Expert. I believe mix page orientation is not possible in this version.